# Filling struct field with getline()

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, getline

Hi guys I'm new to this forum and I wanted to ask for some advice on the code that I wrote.
I'm still learning how to code and my teacher asked me to create a static allocated array of structs with a string field: my problem is that i don't really know how to use getline() to fill it and so I get an error from my IDE:
**[Error] no matching function for call to 'std::basic_istream::getline(std::string [16]**
Here is the code that i used to define the struct:

```cpp
typedef struct{
    string name[16];
    int price;
}dish;
```

And there is the function that I used to fill it:

```
void insertDish(dish menu[], int fill){
    for(int i=0; i<fill; i++){
        cout<<"Enter name and price of dish "<<(i+1)<<": "<<endl;
        cout<<"Name: ";
        cin.getline(menu[i].name);

        cout<<"Price: ";
        cin>>menu[i].price;
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

I'm sorry if there will be some misspelling but English isn't my main language and I tried to translate the code so that it's easier for you to understand it.

P.S. My IDE is Dev-C++

Comment: Please be more specific than "I get an error from my IDE".

Comment: Whatever your error is, you should definitely read [Why does `std::getline()` skip input after a formatted extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)

Comment: @molbdnilo yes you're right, my error is  <[Error] no matching function for call to 'std::basic_istream<char>::getline(std::string [16])'>

Comment: Please add your error message to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `name` as an array of sixteen `std::string`s, and there is no `getline` overload for reading an array of sixteen `std::string`s.

You want either `string name` or `char name[16]` (I would pick the former).

Also, the member `getline` only deals with `char*`.

You need the "free" `getline`:

```
std::getline(std::cin, menu[i].name);
```